# Check the uniform convergence of $\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^ne^{-xn} $

Tags: power-series, uniform-convergence

I have a problem with a power series:

$$\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^ne^{-xn} ~~~~ x\in (0, \infty)$$

Could anyone explain how to check uniform, almost uniform and pointwise convergence? Not only proving convergence is problematic for me, but also exponential function makes me confused.

Comment: What does almost uniform mean? What is the domain of your series?

Comment: How would you calculate sum like this : $\sum (f(x))^n$ and what is the radius of convergence?

Comment: almost uniform: uniformly converge on intervals. I don't know how to translate it from my language :)

Answer (score 0):

*Hint* : Let's consider $\displaystyle \sum_{n\le m} \left(\frac{x}{e^{x}}\right)^{n} = \frac{e^x - x(xe^{-x})^m}{e^x - x}$.

Then your series is limit(with respect to $m$) of following partial sum. When does it converge? When does the limit exist?

Comment: How do you know the sum (right side)? For the the left, I would use Cauchy-Hadamard. The limit would exist for $\ 1 \leq x $ Am I right?

Comment: That's simple progression type series. Consider three cases : $|x e^{-x}| < 1$ , $|xe^{-x}| =1$ and $|xe^{-x}| > 1$.

Comment: How do I know I have to consider especially these cases? Was my reasoning in the proevious post correct?

Comment: @Question 1) there JUST three cases $|a| < 1$ , $|a|= 1$ or $|a| > 1$. 2) Look at this limit $\lim_{m \to \infty} \dfrac{e^x - x(e^{-x} x)^m}{e^x - x}$ when does it exist? 3) No you're wrong , you should also consider a term $e^{-x}$

Comment: The limit exists for $\ m \leq 0 $ I don't know how can I find the idea of this limit? What do I should pay attention to? It isn't obvious for me